Failed to rebuild and start electron app using nodejs v18.20.3
i've electron app that currently running using elecron forge.
the issue is appear whenever i tried to start the project using command
npm run start

It will not working, if i have dependencies on canvas. i know canvas have native modules dependencies. it always said like this if i tried to start the app
Done Building Project "C:\Users\rikim\Documents\appangular\oneapp-ui\node_modules\canvas\build\binding.sln" (default targets) -- FAILED.

Build FAILED.

"C:\Users\rikim\Documents\appangular\oneapp-ui\node_modules\canvas\build\binding.sln" (default target) (1) ->
"C:\Users\rikim\Documents\appangular\oneapp-ui\node_modules\canvas\build\canvas-postbuild.vcxproj.metaproj" (default target) (2) ->
"C:\Users\rikim\Documents\appangular\oneapp-ui\node_modules\canvas\build\canvas.vcxproj" (default target) (3) ->
(ClCompile target) ->
  C:\Users\rikim\.electron-gyp\33.0.2\include\node\v8-primitive.h(616,62): warning C4324: 'v8::String::ValueView': structure was padded due to alignment specifier [C:\Users\rikim\Documents\appangular\oneapp-ui\node_modules\canvas\build\canvas.vcxproj]


"C:\Users\rikim\Documents\appangular\oneapp-ui\node_modules\canvas\build\binding.sln" (default target) (1) ->
"C:\Users\rikim\Documents\appangular\oneapp-ui\node_modules\canvas\build\canvas-postbuild.vcxproj.metaproj" (default target) (2) ->
"C:\Users\rikim\Documents\appangular\oneapp-ui\node_modules\canvas\build\canvas.vcxproj" (default target) (3) ->
(ClCompile target) ->
  C:\Users\rikim\Documents\appangular\oneapp-ui\node_modules\nan\nan_scriptorigin.h(36,23): error C2665: 'v8::ScriptOrigin::ScriptOrigin': no overloaded function could convert all the argument types [C:\Users\rikim\Documents\appangular\oneapp-ui\node_modules\canvas\build\canvas.vcxproj]
  C:\Users\rikim\Documents\appangular\oneapp-ui\node_modules\nan\nan_scriptorigin.h(40,23): error C2665: 'v8::ScriptOrigin::ScriptOrigin': no overloaded function could convert all the argument types [C:\Users\rikim\Documents\appangular\oneapp-ui\node_modules\canvas\build\canvas.vcxproj]
  C:\Users\rikim\Documents\appangular\oneapp-ui\node_modules\nan\nan_scriptorigin.h(47,23): error C2665: 'v8::ScriptOrigin::ScriptOrigin': no overloaded function could convert all the argument types [C:\Users\rikim\Documents\appangular\oneapp-ui\node_modules\canvas\build\canvas.vcxproj]

    1 Warning(s)
    3 Error(s)

Time Elapsed 00:00:02.61
Error: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\MSBuild\Current\Bin\MSBuild.exe` failed with exit code: 1
    at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Users\rikim\Documents\appangular\oneapp-ui\node_modules\@electron\node-gyp\lib\build.js:215:23)
    at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:517:28)
    at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:292:12)

× Rebuild Failed

An unhandled error occurred inside electron-rebuild
node-gyp failed to rebuild 'C:\Users\rikim\Documents\appangular\oneapp-ui\node_modules\canvas'

Error: node-gyp failed to rebuild 'C:\Users\rikim\Documents\appangular\oneapp-ui\node_modules\canvas'
    at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Users\rikim\Documents\appangular\oneapp-ui\node_modules\@electron\rebuild\lib\module-type\node-gyp\node-gyp.js:121:24)
    at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:517:28)
    at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:292:12)

Only when i delete the canvas feature on mywebsite and uninstall it, then it manage to rebuild. I'm using nodejs 18.20.3, electron 33.0.1, and electron forge 7.5.0
Anyone know how to solved this ?

The issue arises because node-canvas has native dependencies that need to be properly rebuilt for compatibility with Electron. The errors are due to mismatches between the version of Electron you are using and the build environment setup for native modules.

Yes you're right, but how to make it run ? my nodejs version is 18.20.3, electron 33.0.1.
Should i downgrade the electron or how

Upgrade your node version to 20.18. Please check Electron version compatibility.

I've upgrade mynodejs version to 20.18. but still get error. any other things i should do ? i've deleted all node_modules and package.lock.json and reinstall all the depdendencies by the way

is it required the cairo & GTK library also for node-canvas ?? maybe thats the cause ?

Yes it is needed for node-canvas

How to specify this gtk library & cairo path during rebuild ??

Hi at the end i replace canvas depdendencies with something else, seems like canvas 2.11 is not really compatible with my electron 33.xx.xx

At the end, i removed my dependencies to canvas.
and it doesn't required native modules anymore ... previously i'm using canvas to show some chart on my websites.
but i replace the library called

echarts

and it doesn't really need canvas again after that
thanks
